# Mixed tensor index position significance

Tags: notation, tensor

What is the significance of tensor index position?

For example the fourth order Riemann curvature tensor
\begin{align}
R^m_{ijk}
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
R^{\phantom{i}m}_{i\phantom{m}jk}.
\end{align}
The latter I have seen in [Lovelock and Rund](https://books.google.no/books?id=ikPQFqxcyfMC&redir_esc=y), while the former in [Heinbockel](https://books.google.no/books/about/Introduction_to_Tensor_Calculus_and_Cont.html?id=4iB5ZB1NN7MC&redir_esc=y).

Another example, is the mixed Kronecker delta
\begin{align}
\delta^i_{\phantom{i}j}
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\delta^{\phantom{j}i}_j.
\end{align}
In [Lovelock and Rund](https://books.google.no/books?id=ikPQFqxcyfMC&redir_esc=y), for any second order tensor, they simply do not mind
having the indices above each other, as for example
\begin{align}
\delta^i_j.
\end{align}
Having to read multiple notations becomes occasionally confusing.

Are there any pitfalls to be aware of with regards to index position?

Comment: There is no significance of the positioning of the indices for the Kronecker delta. For the Riemann curvature tensor, you have to read carefully how the notation is defined in the text. There is unfortunately no standard convention for this.

Comment: I don't know whether this was original with Chern, but he sometimes used a dot to keep track of the relative position of the index when it was raised or lowered, viz. $R_i{{}^j_{\cdot}}_{kl}$, when there might be a possibility of confusion.

Comment: On second thought, there are relatively standard conventions for the Riemann tensor. Recall that the Riemann tensor takes $3$ vectors, say $X,Y,Z$ and returns a vector $R(X,Y)Z$. It is skew-symmetric in $X$ and $Y$. Normally, the last two indices correspond to $X$ and $Y$ and the only issue is where to put the indices of $Z$ and the output vector. My preferred convention is $R^m_{ijk}e_m = R^m{}_{ijk}e_m =  R(e_j, e_k)e_i$. It appears that Heinbockel prefers to write it as $R_i{}^m{}_{jk}e_ m= R(e_j, e_k)e_i$.